# ruby on rails mailer and non-unicode domain (.рф)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicode, dns

my rails app use russian cyrryllic domain name (.рф), and there I have mailer, where i have default from section...

like this:

```
  default from: "noreply@портал.рф"
```

some part of mailer:

```
class CarMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "noreply@портал.рф"


  def send_car_question_back(question_text, question_email, question_phone, car_user, car)
    ****
    mail(to: @question_email, subject: "***")
  end
end
```

but on my mailbox i get noreply@blablabla with some strane numbers( like spam :)

are there any ways to send mail, and put sender in cyryllic format?

in env confg i have:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings =  {
    :enable_starttls_auto => false,
    :address        => 'localhost',
    :port           => 25,
    :domain         => 'xn----7s454545*****i',
    :authentication => :login,
    :content_type   => "text/html",
    :user_name      => 'noreply@xn----7s454545*****i',
    :password       => '*****'
  }
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'xn----7s454545*****i' }
```

Comment: whats mean `blablabla` ? `noreply@xn----7s454545*****i`?

Comment: that is normal domain encoding `'xn----7s454545*****i'` for cyrillic domains, exactly for non-ascii domains.

Comment: you can know it of your domain `портал.рф` keeper

Comment: Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245335/actionmailer-non-ascii-characters

Comment: @asiniy that is not the same problem.

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ but maybe there are any ways to do beatifull "name" ? or it is deprecated ?

Comment: have you tried `:domain         => 'портал.рф',`?

Comment: i think mail server not provide translate to cyrillic domain.

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ 501 5.0.0 Invalid domain name

Answer (score 3):

That `'xn----7s454545*****i'` is normal domain encoding for cyrillic domains, exactly for non-ASCII domains. The domain names conversion approach is described in [RFC 3490](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3490).

Your mailbox just isn't support non-ASCII domain conversion. So you just can try to set domain name in mailer settings as a cyrillic one, and using a IDNA conversion gems to convert it to an ASCII form:

1. For [ruby-1.8](/questions/tagged/ruby-1.8) it is the [`idn` gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/idn) .

   ```
    require 'idn'
   ```

And environment config:

```
    config.action_mailer.smtp_settings =  {
      #...
      :domain         => IDN::Idna.toASCII('портал.рф')
    }
```

And vise-versa:

```
    puts 'Idna.toUnicode: ' + IDN::Idna.toUnicode('xn--rksmrgs-5wao1o.josefsson.org')
```

1. For [ruby-2.0](/questions/tagged/ruby-2.0) you have to use [`simpleidn` gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/simpleidn).

   ```
    require 'idn'

    SimpleIDN.to_ascii("портал.рф")

    SimpleIDN.to_unicode("xn--mllerriis-l8a.com")
   ```

Comment: And vise-versa: - what is this?

Comment: vise-versa is conversion from ascci string to unicode.

Comment: @brabertaser1992 what returns `SimpleIDN.to_ascii("портал.рф")`?

Comment: @brabertaser1992 `SimpleIDN.to_ascii("портал.рф")` should return sometihng like `'xn----7s454545*****i'`.

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ it return so, but i want russian text... (

Comment: @brabertaser1992 you can define it as a rails variable, then just pass it to the `SimpleIDN.to_ascii` method. Mailer shell accept only ASCII letters. Or open the bug issue to the mailer, and wait for fix.